# sed's greediness seemingly violated

Tags: sed

I would have thought these two invocations of `sed` would return the same output given that it looks for patterns in a greedy fashion by default. Why not?

```
$ echo '<a href="/topic/null-hypothesis/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Null hypothesis</a>' | grep -E '<a href="/topic.*</a>' | sed 's/<a href=.*">//'
Null hypothesis</a>

$ echo '<a href="/topic/null-hypothesis/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Null hypothesis</a>' | grep -E '<a href="/topic.*</a>' | sed 's/<a href=.*>//'
```

PS:

```
$ bash --version
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

PS2: I corrected from `sed` to `grep`.

PS3: Corrected back from `grep` to `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any violation here. `">` is matched by the end of `link">`, but not by the end of `</a>`, which is matched by just `>`.

Comment: I didn't say there was a violation, but a seeming one. The interrogation pertains not to the first invocation, but the second: I would like to match the first `>`.

Comment: Well, no violation, seemingly or otherwise. If you would like to match the first `>`, then you will need to exclude `>` from the characters matched in between. `[^>]*>`

Comment: Yes, that's the way to make BRE/ERE non-greedy. BTW @muru, it seems your comment is the answer, and the answer should be a comment.

Comment: @glennjackman dunno, the question asks why the patterns matched what they did, and it's only their comment that has the actual requirement of non-greedy matching.

Comment: I think the reason behind my question is that I understood 'greedy' as 'first match'. Apparently that is not the case.

Comment: @Erwann greedy = match as much as possible